# Cannot resolve Method from DAO

Tags: android, android-room

I am trying a simple Database example using the Room Library.
I have an Alarm class

```
@Entity
public class Alarm{

    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;
    public long alarmtime;

    public Alarm(int id, long alarmtime){
        this.id = id;
        this. alarmtime = alarmtime;
    }

}
```

An AlarmDAO interface,

```
@Dao
public interface AlarmDAO {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void addAlarm(Alarm alarm);

    @Query("select * from Alarm")
    public List<Alarm> getAllAlarm();

    @Query("select * from Alarm where id = :id")
    public List<Alarm> getAlarm(long userId);

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void updateAlarm(Alarm alarm);

    @Query("delete from Alarm")
    void removeAllAlarm();

    }
```

And a AlarmDatabase class,

```
@Database(entities = {Alarm.class}, version = 16, exportSchema = false)
    public abstract class AlarmDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

        private static AlarmDatabase INSTANCE;

        public abstract Alarm AlarmDAO();

        public static AlarmDatabase getDatabase(Context context) {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE =
                        Room.databaseBuilder(context, AlarmDatabase.class, "userdatabase")
                                .allowMainThreadQueries()//remove this line in production
                                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                                .build();
            }
            return INSTANCE;
        }
}
```

In the MainActivity when I try to access a method from the AlarmDAO, it says that it cannot resolve the method,

```
database = AlarmDatabase.getDatabase(this);
database.AlarmDAO().removeAllAlarm();
```

Comment: Have you tried making your DAO functions `public`? If you can please provide error logs.

Comment: Are you getting this same error on all methods?

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli Yes none of the Methods are accessible, even AndroidStudio doesnt give the suggestion for thos methods

Comment: @TomasJablonskis Yes that didnt do anything. How can I implement the UserDao at least

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a field named `AlarmDao` in `AlarmDatabase`. You have a method named `AlarmDAO()`. So, call that `AlarmDAO()` method:

```
database.AlarmDAO().removeAllAlarm();
```

Comment: Thats what I originally did , it doesnt work, updated question too

Comment: @Vedantkarandikar: Java is case-sensitive. Your updated question has `database.AlarmDao().removeAllAlarm()`, which is not the same as `database.AlarmDAO().removeAllAlarm()`.

Answer (score 0):

After analysing all my code, I realized that I had used assigned an `AlarmDAO` to an `Alarm` (which I do not know why was acceptable because they are of different types) So changing this in the AlarmDatabase.java made it start working.

```
@Database(entities = {Alarm.class}, version = 16, exportSchema = false)
    public abstract class AlarmDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static AlarmDatabase INSTANCE;

    public abstract AlarmDAO AlarmDAO();// WAS originally Alarm AlarmDAO();

    public static AlarmDatabase getDatabase(Context context) {
...
```